# How can I let the kernel be updated automatically?

Tags: upgrade, kernel, update-manager

I have Xubuntu 14.04 on my computer. The new stable kernel ver 3.16 have been released for a long time. But, the updater cannot install the new kernel automatically. So I had to install it myself. I want to know how I can let the kernel be updated automatically? Why the updater do not install new stable kernels in time?

Answer (score 2):

You can run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-utopic
```

and you will get kernel 3.16. And it will get security updates automatically.

You can also install 3.19 kernel by

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```